# Overflowing on absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

OK, here's the issue:

I'm trying to put two elements (a textarea and an input), one on top of the other, with the first taking up all of the remaining space.

The elements are `absolute` positioned.

However, when I'm trying setting a `left` property (on any of them), the rightmost part seems to overflow. (Setting the `right` one as well doesn't help at all).

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="the-wrapper">
    <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    <input id="search-input" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert a command &amp; press <Return>" name="cmd-term">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
textarea {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 10px; 
  bottom:50px; 
  left: 10px; 
  overflow:visible;
}

input {
  height:34px; 
  position:absolute; 
  bottom:15px; 
  left:10px;
}
```

**Snippet :** http://www.bootply.com/MAkCQNtiXY

---

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Check out the `form-control` class. It gives the element `width: 100%` and your positioning offsets it by 10px from the left. That's probably pushing it off the edge. You may want to look into Bootstraps grid system to help with your positioning, it'll play friendlier with the `form-control`. Edit: [Grid System Link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: @Shaded Well... I can obviously unset the width, but then how would I go about absolute positioning, stacking the elements, and having the textarea "expand" on parent's resize?

Comment: It'll work if you let the textarea be 100% width and positioned relative (or nothing) and the input be absolute. That will let you position the input on top of the textarea.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon With the grid system you can basically put it in a div that fills a whole row then put the next element in the next row. Bootstrap handles the resizing pretty seamlessly, the answer you accepted will fix the problem, but I think most devs would agree it's a bit of a sloppy solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.form-control` class sets the `width` to be `100%`. The absolute positioned element's width is based on its parent. Since `#the-wrapper` doesn't have a position, the width will be based on the `body`.

You're setting it to be `100%` but misplacing it to the left by `10px`, with the `left` property.

A solution would be to overload the `width` property, "fixing" the left offset with the `calc` value:

```
.form-control {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/vnEI0vl1d5

Comment: One word: Awesome. Thanks a lot! :-)